# How to make Selenium wait for user input?

Tags: user-interface, selenium, automated-tests

I'm doing some test automation on a software. Basically I've many forms to fill up and some final computed results to check. I'd like Selenium to go to a page, then wait for the user fills the form and notify it to Selenium with a dedicated input. So Selenium read these values and bring the user to the following page?

How can I make Selenium wait for the user's input? I can't put a wait neither on an arbitrary time, nor on an expected condition on the Ihm I'm testing.

Comment: Is this not defeating the point of Selenium?

Comment: No. I want the user to execute the test once, then Selenium will be able to reproduce it and I'll add it to my non-regression tests. I can't use the provided Selenium recording feature because it's not compatible with the GUI I'm testing.

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to wait for user input, for a different reason: because I cannot automate the login procedure which requires clicking on an image's cells. But once the user has done that, I'd like to automate all the steps that come after the login....

Answer (score 1):

When I need to pass something specific to my Selenium tests I do it this way:

1) Make runnable `jar` file out of tests  - so the tests can be run by simple command `java -jar mytest.jar`

2) In Java you can pass comand line arguments. The good old

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

is your friend

so if you run the test like `java -jar mytest.jar Hello World`

then inside your code

```
args[0] = "Hello"
args[1] = "World"
```

Example

```
java -jar mytest.jar Pavel mysecretpassword
```

and in the code

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  loginasUser(args[0], args[1])
}


public void loginasUser(String username, String password){
  driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(username);
  driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);
  driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
}
```

Of course, I left out the `WebDriver` initialisation, but I hope you got the idea

Comment: The point isn't to pass Selenium specific arguments, but to make it wait for the user input. The arguments must come from the user doing the test for the first time.

Comment: wait a second. I was reading your comment below the question: OK, you cannot record it via Selenium IDE, but it means that you actually have to write IDs (or paths) to each input field. Why not writing also a values which should go there? Or asking the user?

Comment: I'll try to explain better. I've already developped the Selenium part that run the automised tests based on pre-entered datas. Now, since there's a whole team of people passing "manual" tests I'd like to record the ones they do in order to repeat them automatically later.